# Making sure a PHP array has only sequential keys

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any way to have an array with items like:

```
$array[1];
$array[3];
$array[4];
```

Be turned into an array like this:

```
$array[1];
$array[2];
$array[3];
```

So that the array has only sequential numeric keys? Thanks!

Comment: do you want to renumber the keys starting at zero? If so, therefromhere's answer is perfect.

Comment: Well, all the answers will work for starting for zero. If you just want them to be sequential (not starting from 0), none of the answers will work.

Comment: @Chacha102 You can get an index at one, but it's a pretty hacky solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**`array_values()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array.

Comment: To get a index starting at one, you have to hack around after calling array_values: `$arr = array_unshift($arr, null); unset($arr[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`array_values()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) on that array, and it will return a newly indexed array. (This assumes you have a numerically indexed array of course)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array_merge($array, array());
```

As long as `$array` has numerical keys, it will reorder them (starting from 0), numerically.